# Using $templateCache with ui-router and uglify in angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-templatecache

Sharing this as a Qusstion-answer post.

What to do when you have to use `$templateCache` in `templateProvider` of a route in ui-router and have to utility the code? Injecting does not work, and angular cannot inject by reference.

Example :

```js
...  
templateProvider : function($templatecache) {

    ...

},

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead :

```js
...  
templateProvider : ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {

    ...

}],

...
```